# Play Sound in Different Thread in android app

Tags: android, audio, lag, frame-rate, soundpool

i am working on an app which contains a Wheel to rotate, which is drawing at a speed of 40fps while rotating , i need to play a 'tick ' sound (around 250ms long sound) repeatedly when the wheel is rotating. i tried it but the wheel rotation stuck sometimes while rotating , used soundpool to play the sound. any suggestion to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @pskink thanks for the suggestion . AudioTrack not used till date . will try/

Comment: any other suggestions?